# no module named flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm a beginner to flask, following the installation instructions from the website. I'm using python 3.4 and I've run all the following code in my command prompt

```
$ mkdir myproject
$ cd myproject
$ virtualenv venv
python executable in venv/bin/python
Installing distribute............done.

$ . venv/bin/activate

$ venv\scripts\activate

$ pip install Flask
```

I'm pretty sure the virtualenv is activated since venv is before every line of code. But now I'd like to import flask, but when I start up python in my cmd it says no module named flask. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What operating system are you using?  You use the commands to activate a venv for both windows and unix(-like) systems.

Comment: What is your import statement? Are you importing `flask` (correct), or `Flask` (incorrect).

Comment: I'm using windows and my import statement is from flask import Flask

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the output of `which python` is pointing to the python binary inside your `venv` folder. Also make sure you are doing `from flask import Flask` inside python.

Here's my commands that worked just now

```
$ virtualenv venv
$ cd venv
$ . bin/activate
(venv)$ pip install Flask
(venv)$ python
>>> from flask import Flask
```

Answer (score 0):

## Virtualenv is always activated locally for the console

When you activate virtualenv, the activation is valid for current command line session.

If you open another console, it has completely independent status and initially does not know anything about any virtualenv.

It is perfectly fine, to have multiple consoles open an few of them sharing the same virtualenv.